# Relaxing hypotheses for the mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: riemann-integration

If a function $f$ is continuous in $[0,\Delta]$ it is pretty easy to prove that

$$
\exists c\in(0,\Delta):\frac{1}{\Delta}\,\int_{0}^{\Delta}f(t)dt=f(c)
$$

It is enough to apply Lagrange's to the function $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$. Is it possible to derive the same result assuming only that $f$ is Riemann-integrable in $[0,\Delta]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example consider the Riemann integrable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ defined by

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
1, & \frac{1}{2}<x\leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

Then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$ (For this example $\Delta=1$) which is not equals to $f(c)$ for any $c\in[0,1]$.