# Convergence of Riemann integrals on shrinking interval of integrations

Tags: solution-verification, riemann-integration

For a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is **continuous** on $[0,1]$ it is pretty easy to prove that, $\forall r>0$
$$
\Delta_n^{1-r}\,\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\int_{t_{j-1,n}}^{t_{j,n}}f(t)^2\,dt\right)^r\to \int_0^1f(t)^{2\,r}\,dt
$$
where $t_{j,n}=j/n$ is the equi-spaced partition of $[0,1]$ and $\Delta_n=1/n$ is the distance between two elements of the partition. The proof is straightforward since, assuming $f$ **continuous**, we can apply the mean value theorem
$$
\int_{t_{j-1,n}}^{t_{j,n}}f(t)^2\,dt = f(c_{j,n})^2\,\Delta_n
$$
for a $c_j\in(t_{j-1,n},t_{j,n})$ and then the proof continues by observing that
$$
0\leq \inf_{s\in(t_{j-1,n},t_{j,n})}f(s)^{2\,r}\leq f(c_{j,n})^{2\,r}\leq \sup_{s\in(t_{j-1,n},t_{j,n})}f(s)^{2\,r}<\infty
$$
and so
$$
\Delta_n^{1-r}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\int_{t_{j-1,n}}^{t_{j,n}}f(s)^2\,ds\right)^r = \sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{\int_{t_{j-1,n}}^{t_{j,n}}f(s)^2\,ds}{\Delta_n}\right)^r\,\Delta_n=\sum_{j=1}^nf(c_{j,n})^{2\,r}\,\Delta_n\rightarrow \int_0^1f(s)^{2\,r}\,ds
$$
My guess is that the statement could be generalized to discontinuous functions, for example to cadlag functions with a finite (or perhaps countable) number of jumps in the domain. The main problem is that the [mean value theorem is no longer valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007970/relaxing-hypotheses-for-the-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals), so a different approach should be taken. I thought to apply the theorem on all the sub-intervals in which the function is continuous, would that work or am I loosing something fundamental?